# Issue with Google Sign-In in React App deployed to AWS ALB load balancer

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, google-oauth, aws-application-load-balancer

I've a React app, using react-oauth/google, deployed to AWS EC2 ALB Load balancer.
The sign-in with google feature was working perfectly well on dev localhost:3000

Now when deployed to AWS EC2, it shows this error message, and the sign-in popup is blank:
[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.

In the Google API Console, i registered the OAuth client ID for the EC2 instance as follows:

- Create Credentials - OAuth Client ID - Web applications
- In Authorized Javascript Origins, i added the url for the EC2 lb instance:
  http://k8s-default-awsingre-xxxx-xxxx.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
- I also added above url in the Authorized Redirect URIs as well

Are the above configurations correct for OAuth Client ID ?

-- React Sign-In component:

```
<div className='login-form'>
          <h6 className='login-header'>Login to the App</h6>
          <GoogleLogin 
          clientId="413301367752-xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
          onSuccess={responseMessage} onError={errorMessage} cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'} 
          isSignedIn={true}/>
          <p className='login-error'>{error}</p>
         </div>
```

Sign-in with Google popup should not be blank

Comment: "In Authorized Javascript Origins, i added the url for the EC2 lb instance: http://k8s-default-awsingre-xxxx-xxxx.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com" Is that the URL that shows in your web browser when the UI is making the request? Whatever URL is actually showing in the web browser's address bar is going to be the "correct" URL.

Comment: @MarkB .. yes this is the same ui url. But i wonder whether the url should be in https